# how to delete a backbone model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have created the following code and i'm unable to destroy a model from the backend.

I get a 'model is not defined error'.

I don't know why it cannot find a model? what parameters am i missing? am i wrong in adding this in this list view? should i add it in the models view? and if that is the case i added the save new model in the list view so can't see why i can't add it her.

```
   window.LibraryView = Backbone.View.extend({
            tagName: 'section',
            className: 'mynotes',


            events: {
                "keypress #new-title":  "createOnEnter",                    
                //"keypress #new-content":  "createOnEnter"
                "click .mybutton":  "clearCompleted"

            },


           initialize: function() {
                  _.bindAll(this, 'render');
                  this.template = _.template($('#library-template').html());
                  this.collection.bind('reset', this.render);
                  this.collection.bind('add', this.render);
                  this.collection.bind('remove', this.render);

           },

           render: function() {
                    var $mynotes,
                          collection = this.collection;

                    $(this.el).html(this.template({}));
                    $mynotes = this.$(".mynotes");
                    collection.each(function(mynote) {
                            var view = new LibraryMynoteview({
                                  model: mynote,
                                  collection: collection
                            });
                            $mynotes.append(view.render().el);

                    });
                    return this;
           },

            createOnEnter: function(e) {

                var input = this.$("#new-title");
                var input2 = this.$("#new-content");
                //var msg = this.model.isNew() ? 'Successfully created!' : "Saved!";
                 if (!input || e.keyCode != 13) return;
                // this.model.save({title: this.$("#new-title").val(), content:     this.$("#new-content").val() }, {
                var newNote = new Mynote({title: this.$("#new-title").val(), content: this.$("#new-content").val()});
                this.collection.create(newNote);

            },                                                                              
              clearCompleted: function() {
                       this.model.destroy();
                       this.collection.remove();
              }   







    });
```

Comment: How do you instantiate this view?

Comment: Are you sure your view indeed has a model attribute? I don't see any other reference to it in your view definition.

Answer (score 3):

You have to bind your clearCompleted method to `this`:

```
_.bindAll(this, 'render', 'clearCompleted');
```

Comment: No, you don't. delegateEvents actually binds all events to "view's this" for you before actually handing it to jquery. From the docs: """Using delegateEvents provides a number of advantages over manually using jQuery to bind events to child elements during render. All attached callbacks are bound to the view before being handed off to jQuery, so when the callbacks are invoked, this continues to refer to the view object."""